# How to reduce the gaps in the histogram gnuplot?

Tags: graph, gnuplot, histogram

gnuplot script:

```
set auto x
set yrange [0:100] 
set style data histogram 
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid border -1 
set boxwidth 1  
plot 'test.data' using 1, '' u 2
```

test.data

```
80   15
71   81
81   71
61   75
57   17
80   80
82   91
86   73
```

output:
[image]

I need so:
[image]

How to reduce the gaps in the histogram gnuplot?

Comment: Just curious--where did you get the correct plot for the same data if you don't have the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot do this with the clustered histogram style, because the `gap` option takes only integer numbers.

In your case with only two columns, you can use the `boxes` plotting style and shift the boxes belonging to the first column by half of the boxwidth to the left, and the boxes of the second column by the same amount to the right:

```
set auto x
set yrange [0:100] 
set style fill solid border -1
boxwidth=0.45

set boxwidth 0.45 absolute
set style data boxes
plot 'test.data' using ($0-boxwidth/2):1, '' u ($0+boxwidth/2):2
```

Result with 4.6.4:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/histograms.html reports that you can use the "at x-coord" option with newhistogram in gnuplots to manually adjust the gap between clusters. I have used a combination of this, the "gap" option for set style histogram and "set offsets " command to move the clusters around on the graph. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for the `gap` keyword to the `set style histogram` command.

```
set style histogram clustered gap <width of gap>
```

Comment: gap option takes only integer numbers