# gnuplot histogram bars empty space

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying a very easy gnuplot graph. 
Data is

```
Average 0.177 0.167
Median 0.179 0.173
```

and graph code:

```
set style fill solid border 0
set boxwidth 1.5
set style histogram clustered
set style data histograms
plot "PDR.txt" using 2:xtic(1) lt rgb "#406090",\"" 0" using 3 lt rgb "#40FF0
```

problem is that the graph produced has way too much space everywhere, in the middle, but especially left and right. How can I reduce those?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reduce the gaps in the histogram gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166751/how-to-reduce-the-gaps-in-the-histogram-gnuplot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the xrange to the desired length, e.g. `set xrange [-0.25:1.5]` looks alright on my computer

Comment: It only solves the problem partially (the left and the right spaces). I think the real deal is to remove the space between... `:-)`

Comment: for this you could set reduce the magins of the plot using `set Smargin N` where S is either l,r,t,b for the side (left,right,top,bottom) and N is a number between 0 and 1